# Array and matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, arduino

Python newbie here.

Currently I'm making a heartbeat signal detector with an Arduino for my school project.

I want to draw a plotter graph with a signal value that I sent from Arduino to Python, but I'm still not sure  exact way to make a correct array and plot it in Python.

My arduino is connected with bluetooth module, and it is continuously send double integer value around 30~40 times/second.

In Python,I want to write a script that will receive 20 seconds of data, store it in a file, and plot it.

I built my code based on my basic C knowledge.

```
import serial, sys
from time import sleep
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def read_BLE( ser ):
  msg = ""
  if( ser.in_waiting > 0 ):
        msg = ser.readline( ser.in_waiting ).decode('utf-8')
  return msg

with serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600, timeout=1) as ser:
 while(True) :


  max_time = int(input('20'))     #limit time : 20seconds
  start_time = time.time()  # remember when we started

  while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:   
    values = []
    currenttime = []
    i,j=0

    currenttime[i] = (time.time() - start_time)
    values[j] = read_BLE( ser )
                    i += 1
                    j += 1


plt.plot(currenttime, values)
```

Comment: very strange formatting .. I'm pretty sure python will not accept this kind of indentation. Is this what you actually have in file?

Comment: Maybe I have made some errors when I'm uploading it. fixed it

Comment: Don't mix tabs and spaces when doing indention in Python code. It potentially can leas to all kinds of problems since whitespace is significant in the language. I also suggest you read and start following the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restructured part of your code, fixed a couple of breaking bugs, now it should work assuming your other parts of code is correct:

```
with serial.Serial(port='COM7', baudrate=9600, timeout=1) as ser:
    values = [] # Initiate your list before the loop!
    currenttime = [] 
    max_time = 20     #limit time : 20seconds
    start_time = time.time()  # remember when we started
    while True:
        if (time.time() - start_time) > max_time:
            break # if time elapsed larger than max_time, break out of loop
        currenttime.append(time.time() - start_time)
        values.append(read_BLE(ser)) # python list has no set length. just append to it.

plt.plot(currenttime, values)
```

Python `list` has no fixed memory allocation, `.append` will always add a element without causing memory issue -> It's just reference passing really. You also want to initiate your `list` before loop other wise each loop will overwrite and have a new `list`